# Hour Wise Sorting Against Integer Values

Tags: mysql

I am working on MYSQL 5.6 and I have following integer values:

`1
2
3
21
22
23
0`

Wants to sort hour wise and wants to show my results in this format:

`3
2
1
0
23
22
21`

Comment: And what format exactly is that? where does 12 and 13 fits in?

Comment: Why not `23, 22, 21, 3, 2, 1, 0`?

Comment: 12 & 13 are fall into PM section. Its normal time values from 0 to 23.

Comment: wants to show history from current time(3): like   21,22,23,00,1,2,3

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a correlated date value.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Definitely an oddly shaped question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 0 to 24:

```
SELECT
Quantity,
SEC_TO_TIME(Quantity*60*60) as TimeFormat,
CASE WHEN SEC_TO_TIME(Quantity*60*60) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '12:00:00' THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END AS AMPM
FROM your_table
ORDER BY AMPM ASC, TimeFormat DESC
```

Quantity: column with your integer value

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of a new table that maintains sorting for you. It could then be maintained by a non-programmer who may change their mind regarding the business rules. You could easily create a web form that maintains this table.

```
# table sorter

hour     sortOrder
----     ----------

0           10
1           0
2           8
3           7
4           6
5           5
6           4
7           3
8           2
9           1
10          11
11          12
12          13
13          14
14          15
15          16
16          17
17          18
18          19
19          20
20          21
21          22
22          23
23          24
```

Your original table

```
# table things

data               hour
----               -------
'something'         2
'something else'    4
```

Then join this table with SQL

```
select * from things t
join sorter s
on t.hour = s.hour
order by s.sortOrder
```